# RegExp com apenas uma letra

Tags: javascript, regex

Queria fazer uma `RegExp` que ficasse mais ou menos asssim `0000-x`, que ficasse disponível apenas a letra X e números de 0 a 9. Dei uma pesquisada na net, consegui fazer apenas com números ou que pegasse todas as letras.

Aqui tá um exemplo que fiz, apenas com números: http://jsfiddle.net/1pmwau62/

Comment: `X` você deseja que seja um número ?

Comment: Não, `x` seria a unica letra que poderia ser colocada no input

Comment: 0000-A seria uma entrada válida, certo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar um conjunto:

```
[xX\d] para 0 a 9 OU x
[0-9xX] para 0 a 9 OU x
[xX] para SOMENTE x
```

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
v=v.replace(/^(\d{4})([0-9x])/g,"$1-$2");
```

Quando você usa conjuntos em *RegExp*, está dizendo "qualquer destes caracteres". Exemplos:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9] Qualquer letra minúscula ou maiúscula, ou os dígitos de 0 a 9
[abcdABCD]{2} Qualquer combinação de 2 caracteres como aB, DD, Da, db, etc
```

Comment: Mas ainda pude colocar outras letras, a diferença é que com o `x` a mascará funciona

Comment: @AltembergAndrade eu estou respondendo sobre o regexp, agora, pode ser que sua função de máscara tenha algum problema, o que é uma pergunta completamente diferente.

Comment: Testei aqui sua função, e ela formata corretamente os dados. O que acontece é que sua função não é uma máscara de digitação, e sim uma máscara de formatação. Ela aplica a máscara quando o digitado corresponde ao regex. Se você quer filtrar o que foi digitado, precisa rever a função toda.

Comment: É, entendi @Bacco. Eu tava com essas duvidas aí de RegExp rsrs. Eu vou tentar fazer com que aceite apenas a letra X. Vlw ^^

Comment: @AltembergAndrade dê uma olhada nestas perguntas, talvez algo ajude (aí você usa o formato que eu comentei na resposta): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=máscara+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: `[0-9]{4}[xX]` seria o mais adequado desse modo

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio no enunciado ele diz que pode ser X ou de 0 a 9 (se bem que no comment ele diz outra coisa, entao fica complicado :) ). De qq forma, o problema é outro, é na função de filtro. Nem sei se é o caso de fechamento.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio na dúvida atualizei a resposta com os 2 casos no começo.